# Differential equation with derivatives on both sides

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was doing some differential equations while following lessons online and was just wondering if what I found written there is correct.

Given differential equation: $y''=xy'+y'+1$ we're trying to make both left and right side derivatives of some functions like: $f'(x)=g'(x) \implies f(x)=g(x)+c$.
What my tutor did is:


$(y')'=(xy)'+1$
$(y')'=(xy+x)'$
$y'=xy+x+c_1$

etc.

I am curious if this is wrong or I haven't understood this so far. If $y=y(x)$ then $(xy)'$ should be $(xy)'=y+xy'$, right? How do you get from $(xy)'$ following:  $xy'+y'$?

Comment: Was there any mistake? If the derivatives are with respect to $x$ then $x'=1$

Comment: You should ask from the beginning: Why the equation has a $x'$? That's just $1$, so the equation simplifies to $y'' = y'+2$

Comment: Sorry, @jjagmath, there was a typo. Can you check now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. Probably the equation your tutor tried to write was $y''=xy'+y+1$. Then what he did makes sense.

Comment: Thank you, just lack of confidence.